R ggplotly not maintaining margins from ggplot object
I'm creating a group of bar charts in R using facet_grid and because some of my grid labels are long, I'm increasing the margins and rotating the labels so they fit using margin = margin(15, 10, 15, 10), angle = 0.
This works well when I render the ggplot object showing expanded margins/label boxes, but when I pass to ggplotly, the margins seem to revert to a default size with the graph taking most of the canvas that I haven't been able to change yet.  I'm not able to upload images from my work computer, but the Reprex below should illustrate what I'm talking about.
Any ideas as to how I can maintain these margins in the ggplotly output?
**Reprex: **
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

values = rnorm(n = 12, mean = 0, sd = .3)
category = rep(c("long_category_one", "long_category_two", "long_category_three"), 4)
metric = paste0("m",seq(1, 12, 1))
df <- data.frame(metric, category, values)

p_test <- ggplot(data = df, aes(y = metric, x = values, fill = values >= 0)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(vars(category), scales = "free_y", space = "free") +
  theme(
    strip.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(15, 10, 15, 10), angle = 0),
    legend.position = "none"
  )

p_test

ggplotly(p_test)


Perhaps there is an option to achieve your desired result more easily. But one option would be to manipulate the plotly object, i.e. increase the margin on the right of the plot, increase the width of the shapes used to fake the strip background and shift the annotations used to fake the strip text:
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)

values <- rnorm(n = 12, mean = 0, sd = .3)
category <- rep(c("long_category_one", "long_category_two", "long_category_three"), 4)
metric <- paste0("m", seq(1, 12, 1))
df <- data.frame(metric, category, values)

p_test <- ggplot(data = df, aes(y = metric, x = values, fill = values >= 0)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(vars(category), scales = "free_y", space = "free") +
  theme(
    strip.text.y = element_text(
      margin = margin(15, 10, 15, 50), 
      angle = 0
    ),
    legend.position = "none"
  )

p <- ggplotly(p_test) |> 
  layout(
    margin = list(r = 160)
  )

for (i in seq(2, 6, 2)) {
  p$x$layout$shapes[[i]]$x1 <- 140  
}

for (i in 3:5) {
  p$x$layout$annotations[[i]]$xshift <- 10
}

p


